# Uso o vscode com o node, mas nao mostra meus codigos em js no output, eu uso o code runner tbm

Tags: javascript, node.js, visual-studio-code

resolvi aprender javascript num curso, entao baixei o node e vscode, instalei tudo direitinho, coloquei o code runner, ai na hora de eu executar um simples código como console.log('Olá, Mundo'), não aparece nada no output. aparece o running node e etc, ai embaixo que deveria parecer a msg, n aparece. o que fazer? me ajudem, pf

Comment: Verifique se instalou as extensões requisitadas corretamente!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Olá,

Você pode pressionar a tela `F5` no arquivo `.js` que irá executar o código em `Debug Console`. Assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Você pode executar no próprio Console de seu sistema operacional também (Se estiver usando Windows, tente usar o Windows Powershell). Deste modo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: muito obrigado! conseguir visualizar o código, mas tipo, toda vez tenho que desbugar ele, certo? sabe me dizer o porque acontece isso?

Comment: Nesse caso, vai ter que debugar toda vez, caso você queira automatizar isso (atualizar automaticamente toda vez que o arquivo é modificado), você pode usar o [nodemon](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon), basta você usar `npm init`, `npm install -s nodemon` e usar `nodemon arquivo.js`